# How to remove numbering in the J2ME menu (Command)

Tags: java, java-me

Is it possible to remove the numbering in the menu of J2ME application? or to replace the number with other symbols?
I have tried to modify the priority in the Command constructor, but this only changes the order of the menu.

```
new Command("Regular Expense",Command.ITEM,1);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK Its not possible to customize commands using standard LCDUI components. Look at this article, [Customizing the look and feel of Command menu items.](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/TSJ000425_-_Customizing_the_look_and_feel_of_Command_menu_items) I suggest you can use some [third party framework](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Java_ME_UI_Frameworks) developing Java ME application. LWUIT is good one to use.

Comment: ok... I got it. @bharath Thanks a lot for pointing me to the third party frameworks. They look interesting.